# Importing financial history into mint.com

Tags: migrate-data, mint.com

Now that MS Money is no longer viable, I need to move to some other money management tool. Is it possible to import your historical financial records into mint.com? I have six years of history in Microsoft Money that I don't want to lose.

Comment: You might also be interested in http://www.basicallymoney.com/questions/19/what-can-i-replace-microsoft-money-with-now-that-ms-has-abandoned-it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is currently available. I'd recommend putting in your vote for this feature on their [GetSatisfaction site](http://satisfaction.mint.com/mint/topics/import_from_excel_or_comma_seperated_values_csv_files_to_sync_weekly_monthly).

Comment: The GetSatisfaction site is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

According to [2million's Personal Finance Blog](http://www.2millionblog.com/2010/01/moving_from_ms_money_to_mintcom.html), no:

> **Mint.com**
>
> Pros: Free! Web based so no software required and could access on any computer. Web design seems very slick for categorizing expenses, etc.
>
> Cons: Transactions limited to web access financial accounts. No real ability to keep up transactions in other accounts or "buckets" in your personal finances. Reporting features seem more limited to what I am use to with MS Money. No ability to import the years of data I have with MS Money.

However a possible alternative is [Quicken](https://www.thebalance.com/when-replacing-microsoft-money-1293812):

> Quicken has a Microsoft Money data converter, but not all data transfers easily because of differences in database structures.